# Deleting a table in another table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that contains another table which I want to remove with jQuery.
This table is in one of the rows of the original table and I actually want to remove the row.
The original table is a jQuery object with the name table.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>      
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have tried different ways like the following 4 examples, but without any success:

```
if ($(table).is('tr')){
    if (('tr').(':has(table)') $('tr').remove(); 
}

if ($(table, 'tr').has('table')) {
    $(table).find('table').remove();
};

if ($(table, 'tr').has('table')) {
    $('tr').remove();
};

$(table, 'tr').siblings().children('table').remove();
```

I am not sure whether I am on the right track or barking up the completely wrong tree!!

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe a silly question, but can you not just add an id or a class to the second table when it is created and the select it with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested and working fine:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/2JfhA/**

```
$('table').find('table').closest('tr').remove();
```

what this is doing : `first get the first table` and `then find and child table` in it and then `remove the closest tr` which has this table.

checkout the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I come up with

```
​$('table').find('table').parents('tr').remove()​​​;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVWz2/)

Answer (score 0):

Give the row an ID when you create it, will make removing it a lot easier later on and makes the DOM search a lot more efficient

Answer (score -1):

This would be enough

```
$(table).find('table').parents("tr").eq(0).remove();
```

You don't need any "if" because if there is no nested table, there is nothing to remove.

Comment: The OA actually want to remove the row containing the table, not the table itself...

Comment: There is no element: $(table) <-- needs quotes

Comment: i think table is some dom element author uses